# XNA - Moving an animated rectangle horizontaly (no user input, but timer)

Tags: c#, timer, xna, rectangles

Here I want to move this animated rectangle horizontaly without user input, using timer, maybe? The animated rectangle should move left and right (from starting point to end point, whole path = 315 pixels). I mean 315 pixels between point 1 (start on the left) and point 2 (end on the right).
Here's my code:
Variables:

```
        //Sprite Texture
        Texture2D texture;
        //A Timer variable
        float timer = 0f;
        //The interval (300 milliseconds)
        float interval = 300f;
        //Current frame holder (start at 1)
        int currentFrame = 1;
        //Width of a single sprite image, not the whole Sprite Sheet
        int spriteWidth = 32;
        //Height of a single sprite image, not the whole Sprite Sheet
        int spriteHeight = 32;
        //A rectangle to store which 'frame' is currently being shown
        Rectangle sourceRect;
        //The centre of the current 'frame'
        Vector2 origin;
```

Next, in the `LoadContent()` Method:

```
       //Texture load
       texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("gameGraphics\\Enemies\\Sprite");
```

The `Update()` Method:

```
    //Increase the timer by the number of milliseconds since update was last called
    timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    //Check the timer is more than the chosen interval
    if (timer > interval)
    {
        //Show the next frame
        currentFrame++;
        //Reset the timer
        timer = 0f;
    }
    //If we are on the last frame, reset back to the one before the first frame (because currentframe++ is called next so the next frame will be 1!)
    currentFrame = currentFrame % 2;
    sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
    origin = new Vector2(sourceRect.Width / 2, sourceRect.Height / 2);
```

And finally, the `Draw()` Method:

```
    //Texture Draw
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(263, 554), sourceRect,Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

So I want to move `sourceRect`. Ir must loop left and right.

Comment: No the animation's ok, but I need the rectangle MOVE not ANIMATING ON ONE PLACE.

Comment: What is the 'new Vector(263, 554)' parameter?

Comment: It shows the position of the rectangle.

Comment: That's what you should be updating, then, I believe. It's been a while since I worked with XNA, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `spriteBatch.Draw()` call keeps using the same value for the `destinationRectangle`. How do you want it to move? 5 pixels to the right for each frame for example? Just change your `destinationRectangle` (2nd argument to `spriteBatch.Draw()`) to:

```
new Vector2(263 + (currentFrame * 5), 554);
```

EDIT: Example requested from comments

```
class Foo
{
    int x;
    int maxX = 400;

    void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (x++ >= maxX)
            x = 263;
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(263 + x, 554), sourceRect,Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

You would, of course, keep all of your current code except for the spriteBatch.Draw() call the same; you would simply be adding the `x` parts.

Comment: It just blinks between the desired points, I want to SEE how while animating it MOVES (doesn't blink) from point 1 to point 2. However this was usefull. Please reply.

Comment: You could create a field called `x` that you increment in your `Update()` function. Then you could use that to offset your `destionationRectangle`: `new Vector2(263 + x, 554);`

Comment: I'm new so can I have an example?

Comment: OK, thanks, but I need it looping when it gets to point 2 it should get back to point 1 and repeat. Just this and I'll make this answer, please reply.

Comment: I've edited my answer again as requested. Basically, I introduced the `maxX` field.